# how to store web usercontrol in viewstate

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, ascx

I am trying to register a user control in web page and on page unload user control's viewstate save in web page's hidden field.

```
((HiddenField)(this.Page.FindControl("Hidden_LocationUC"))).Value = this.ViewState.ToString();
```

When again page load then user control load from hidden field but I am unable to store view state in hidden field.

```
this.ViewState = ((HiddenField)(this.Page.FindControl("Hidden_LocationUC"))).Value;
```

This code is results in error.

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is a `collection` of type `StateBag` and you are trying to `assign` a `string` to it which causes error. You are not supposed to change the view state of page instead you need to add and get the objects in the view state collection.

To store a string in ViewState.

```
ViewState["YourObjectName"] = "SomeValue";
```

To Retrieve the Value from ViewState

```
string str = ViewState["YourObjectName"].ToString();
```

If you are interested in **custom ViewState mangement** you can use [**IStateManager**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.istatemanager.aspx)